# how to change the size of a fixed header

Tags: css, header, styles, angular-material, sidenav

this is a part of my project : [app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-3xetzg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage-layout%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html)

I want the header be fixed in scrolling and I added bootstrap `fixed-top` class to my header in header.component.html file. but when I change the mode of my sidenav to `side` the header doesn't change and be pushed to left.
how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to used bootstrap's `fixed-top` - you just need to place your header in the right place. For your 'side' mode, the header needs to be inside the sidenav content so that it is pushed along with the content. For 'over' mode, the header needs to be above and outside the sidenav altogether. You can do this using template logic:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!pushed" [ngTemplateOutlet]="appHeader"></ng-container>

<mat-sidenav-container class="theme-sidenav-container" autosize>

    <mat-sidenav class="theme-sidenav" #sidenav [mode]="mode" position="end" opened="false" (mouseleave)="pushed? 2+2 :sidenav.toggle()">
        ...
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content class="theme-main-content">

        <ng-container *ngIf="pushed" [ngTemplateOutlet]="appHeader"></ng-container>

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>

<ng-template #appHeader>
  <app-header (toggleSidenav)="sidenav.toggle()" [menuAvailable]="pushed"></app-header>
</ng-template>
```

Here it is on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-3xetzg-repcux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage-layout%2Fsidenav%2Fsidenav.component.html). Note that I also removed the `fixed-top` class and defined defaults for `mode` and `pushed`.

This may not be exactly what you want, but it shows you how to dynamically change the header position. You may need to add layout to app-sidenav and the theme-main-content class.

Comment: Thank you so much. it's really helpful. I can apply it to my project. is the header fixed when the app has content and needs scrolling?

Comment: I don't think it is fixed - you would need to set its position to absolute to make it sticky, and you may need to adjust the content position to below the sticky header in order to avoid having content overlayed by the header.